# What is the problem with the following c++ code?

Tags: c++, string-comparison

The problem is 12289 - One-Two-Three from Online Judge at https://onlinejudge.org/external/122/12289.pdf
I have to compare a given string s with the following: "one","two","three", and return a number that indicates which of those has the most correct characters in a correct position with the string.
The following is my attempt at getting an accepted answer.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char c;
    int t,len,c1,c2;
    scanf("%d\n",&t);
    while(t--){
        len = 0;
        c1 = 0;
        c2 = 0;
        while(true){
            scanf("%c",&c);
            if(c=='\n') break;
            if("one"[len] == c) c1++;
            if("two"[len] == c) c2++;
            len++;
        }
        if(len>3) printf("%d\n",3);
        else if (c1>c2) printf("%d\n",1);
        else printf("%d\n",2);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am getting a "Wrong answer" in this question, that usually does not involve formatting problems. I am new to C++ so it would help me a lot to know in what can I improve.

Comment: What happens when `len` is 3 or more????  Use a debugger. :-)  *Hint: `"one"[4]`*

Comment: Since you aren't use any C++ specific features, you may want to compile and code using C.  The C++ language has `std::string` and C doesn't.

Comment: The program basically ignores that I think.
`3
twoone
onetwo
twotwo`
gives
`
3
3
3
`

Comment: *I am new to C++* -- You should think about how to approach the problem before writing any code.  The question at the site has very little to do with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your support. I discovered that the real problem was the formatting of the input. There were blank lines between two consecutive inputs, so the part of `if(c=='\n') break;` was causing some trouble.
Anyways, I will try to remake the solution following C++ guidelines. I just did not know how to process a string, so I thought of doing it character by character. I'm closing the thread.

Answer (score 1):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews) says, you should check if len is > 3. Strings are basically character arrays terminated by the null byte or '\0'. In memory this is represented as ['o', 'n', 'e', '\0', ?, ...] wherein the ? is garbage value or, as C/C++ calls it, illegal memory access. So, there is a chance that "one"[4] == c or "two"[4] == c to be true since we do not know the value stored there. If that happens then the line

```c
    else if (c1>c2) printf("%d\n",1);
```

would have a problem.